# Restrict Contacts REST API routes

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I've been using several of the Delete Contact REST API routes, of which there are several:

- Delete Contacts by ID
- Delete Contacts by Key
- Delete Contacts by List Reference
- Get Status of the Contact Delete Operation
- Retry Failed Delete Request

I've observed that there are now a similar set of routes to 'Restrict Contacts':

- [Restrict Contacts by ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/restrict-contact-id.htm)
- [Restrict Contacts by Key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/restrict-contact-key.htm)
- [Restrict Contacts by List Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/restrict-contact-listreference.htm)
- [Get Status of the Contact Restrict Operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ContactsRestrictStatus.htm)
- [Retry Failed Restrict Request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/RetryContactRestrict.htm)

I'm trying to figure out what these routes actually do, and what does it mean to "restrict" a Contact? The documentation is quite vague. Is anyone familiar with these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in '[Restrict Data Processing for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=restriction_of_processing_marketing.htm&type=5)'

> Various laws and regulations require you and your company to sometimes restrict the processing of your customers’ data.
>
> When situations require you to do so, prevent the processing of your customers’ data. We give guidance to help you restrict forms of data processing. That way, you can work toward complying with the laws that are important to your company.

[Understanding the right to restrict processing](https://www.itgovernance.eu/blog/en/the-gdpr-understanding-the-right-to-restrict-processing)